# Not being able to receive messages from websocket server

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket

I am not sure why I can't receive the data send from the server.

Server is written in node.js using https://github.com/websockets/ws and I use their examples to set up the server. This is how I send data:

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

   ws.on('open', function (){
   ws.send('You are logged');
   })

   ws.send('something');
});
```

This is how I receive data in c# using ClientWebSocket

```
public static async Task ReceiveData(ClientWebSocket ws)
    {
        ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[8192]);

        WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;
        while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
           {
               using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
               {
                    do
                    {
                        result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                        ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
                     }
                     while (!result.EndOfMessage);

                     ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
                         Console.WriteLine( reader.ReadToEnd());
              }
           }
    }
```

The problem is that I receive "something" once. My goal is that I want to receive the message "You are logged" every second?

Edit: Clarification... The problem is that the message within ws.on('open',..) is not sent for some reason?

Appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ws.on('open', function (){
    ws.send('You are logged'); 
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (ws) 
            ws.send('You are logged');
        else
            clearInterval(timer);
    }, 1000);
});
```

?

Comment: The problem is that the message within ws.on('open', function(){ws,send('some message') ;} it is not sent at all. The only string I receive is "something" which is after the ws.on('open',...)